# Javascript regex select word without special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match word without special characters(dot, quotes, etc.) or whitespaces. The text I have

> "üstlenmeyeceğimizin üst "ürünlerin daha sağlıklı ve zamanında ulaşabilmesi süstlenmeyeceğimizin şehirlerarası otobüs şirketleriyle çalıştığımızı fakat ısrarınız üstüne oluşabilecek gecikme veya sorunları üstlenmeyeceğimizin teyidini alarak kargoyla gönderim sağladık." üstlenmeyeceğimizin ğtest atest üstlenmeyeceğimizind. test test üst şüst a ğüst .üst üst.büst she sells seashells tüst  atest ni ani  grüst
>   asla ısrar etmedim ve ürünlerin sağlığı için i yi olduğuna dair bi r bilgilendirme yapılmadı.

I want to select **üst** from this text but there is some different situations like below.

I don't want match words listed below

- ğ**üst**
- ş**üst**
- **üst**lenmeyeceğimizin
- "**üst**lenmeyeceğimizin

I want select those listed words

- .**üst**
- **üst** (there is whitespace before word)
- "üst

I wrote this regex: `[^a-zçğşöü]üst(?![a-zçğşöü])` but this regex selects word with special characters. I don't want special characters.

Shortly I don't want select if word has any leading letters or whitespace but if there is any special character leading the word I want to select it without this special character

Comment: Use groups, `(^|[^a-zçğşöü])(üst)(?![a-zçğşöü])`, then do whatever you need with captures.

Comment: Why dont you just omit the special characters in your regex? 
[^a-z]üst(?![a-z])

Comment: @Ephedra because it sees Turkish characters as special characters too ? https://regexr.com/4ajv6

Comment: @arif: do you also want to match `tüst` and `grüst` in your text? As well as `büst` and `üstüne`? or you do not need those words?

Comment: @Allan no I just want to match `üst`

Comment: @arif: then check the first part of my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to match words and replace them with html tags, for example:

```
üst -> <b>üst</b>
```

I solved my problem with this regex

```
([^a-zçğşöü])üst(?![a-zçğşöü])
```

This regex also matches whitespaces and special characters but I grouped them in regex then excluded from html tags when replacing.

Regex test: https://regexr.com/4amj3

Working example: https://codepen.io/asipek/pen/xBQGPK?editors=0011

Answer (score 1):

If you do really want only those 3 words:

> I want select those listed words
>
> - .üst
> - üst (there is whitespace before word)
> - "üst

As you have asked in your question, then should be enough:

```
[" .]üst\b
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/kfMZxr/1/

If now you want to include whole words in your matches use:

```
(?!şğ)[^\s]*üst(?!lenmeyeceğimizin)[^\s]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/kfMZxr/2

This will allow matches as `tüst` and `grüst` in your text as well as `büst` and `üstüne`.

(based on: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is no "üst in your text, you mean "üstlenmeyeceğimizin ? 
any way check this  [.\s"]üst\b you can test it 
 [here](https://regex101.com/r/eJKtua/1)